# Web3.js installation error on windows

Tags: node.js, git, npm, web3js

When i try to install web3.js i get this error:

My system config is:

windows 7

node: v6.11.0

npm: 3.10.10

`npm i ethereum/web3.js --save`

`npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url npm WARN addRemoteGit npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit ethereum/web3.js resetting remote C:\Users\afeyzi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-ethereum-web3-js-git-6339a8c5 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url npm WARN addRemoteGit npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as
_onclose] (net.js:497:12) npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false, npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1, npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null, npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }`

Comment: Your version of npm is pretty old. Try upgrading. Also, if you're running npm in cygwin, try running it through a standard command prompt (There are sometimes issues with npm on cygwin).

Answer (score 3):

Install web3 using following command to install the latest version of web3 (1.0.0-beta.34 currently).

```
npm install web3
```

Also --save tag is depreciated now, package will be added to dependency as a default. To not include a package in dependency use tag --no-save.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like git error due to wrong npm package,
try

```
npm install --save web3@0.20.6
```

or new version

`npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26`

> you need to be installed windows-build-tools for Windows

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution ( Linux, Windown7 , Windows10 )

git download & install

https://git-scm.com/downloads

And then,

c:\NodeJs\node_ethereum>npm install web3 --save

npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ??  WARNING ?? tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm WARN node_ethereum@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN node_ethereum@1.0.0 No repository field.

- web3@1.0.0-beta.37
  updated 1 package and audited 99531 packages in 5.263s
  found 0 vulnerabilities

Good Lucky!

http://digital2u.co.kr/board/form/view/tip/916/1/55